# Animation Nodes - Replicate an object on an already replicated object

Tags: animation-nodes

In the following example, I do have a spline replicated. Now I want to place an icosphere on all of the splines. Can't find a way of doing this.

[image]

In short I have a mesh replicated on a spline, then I want to replicate this entire system on a new instancer/replicator. In this case, a circular replicator spline.

[image: replicated splines]

Answer (score 1):

Use a "Get Length" node to create the same amount of icosphereinstances as there are splines.

Create a Loop subprogram to loop through the spline list.

we can now use a replicate spline node to get info for each of the splines and position the icospheres accordingly.

Use the spline and object lists as iterator inputs and connect them to the evaluate spline and an object transform output node.

invoke the subprogram.

You can use the parameter of the evaluate spline node to offset the icosphere along the splines.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. It was very helpfull to understand a little more. However, that wasn't the exactly problem I had in mind, sorry for not be clearer. Indeed, I do need icospheres in each replicated splines, but I want each spline to have lots of icospheres, not only one. What are your thoughts?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thats basically just another loop width offsets. I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In short: I have a mesh replicated on a spline, then I want to replicate this entire system on a new instancer/replicator. In this case, a circular replicator spline. Thank for your help!